# css-grid: having a column with a different number of rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following layout:

```css
.container {
  width: 630px;
  height: 630px;
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

.first, .second, .third, .fourth, .fifth, .sixth, .seventh {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.first, .second {
  height: 400px;
}

.fourth {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.seventh {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='first'>1</div>
  <div class='second'>2</div>
  <div class='third'>3</div>
  <div class='fourth'>4</div>
  <div class='fifth'>5</div>
  <div class='sixth'>6</div>
  <div class='seventh'>7</div>
</div>
```

I would like the first and second column to have 2 rows, taking `3fr 1fr` and the last column to have 3 rows taking up `2fr 1fr 1fr`. The end result would be that box number 4 is nested between number 3 and 7 without breaking out of the rectangle that boxes in the first two columns created.

This final positioning should look like this:
[image: boxes]

Is this possible using css grid, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.first,
.second,
.third,
.fourth,
.fifth,
.sixth,
.seventh {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.first,
.second {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.second,
.sixth {
}

.fourth {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='first'>1</div>
  <div class='second'>2</div>
  <div class='third'>3</div>
  <div class='fourth'>4</div>
  <div class='fifth'>5</div>
  <div class='sixth'>6</div>
  <div class='seventh'>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sry, I edited the question my intention was not clear from the first post and example. I do appreciate the effort though.

Comment: *width: 100%;
   height: 100%;* can be removed, the alignment is by default stretch

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted.

You can read more about `grid-row` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row)

Run snippet to see it working below

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.first,
.second,
.third,
.fifth,
.sixth,
.seventh {
  background-color: pink;
}

.first,
.second {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.fourth {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='first'>1</div>
  <div class='second'>2</div>
  <div class='third'>3</div>
  <div class='fourth'>4</div>
  <div class='fifth'>5</div>
  <div class='sixth'>6</div>
  <div class='seventh'>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sry if I was unclear - I do not want empty spaces (an empty row) between boxes 1 and 5 and 2 and 6, but want the top row height of the first two columns to be `3fr`. The problem is that I have expanding content inside the row (the boxes are just for demonstrative purposes). I could probably just make the content expand over the row with a fixed height, but that seems really bad since the layout uses relative units (fractions) to accomodate resizing...

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič updated the answer - is that it ? You need to edit you question as well where you are telling the final positioning like this. The image in the question is exactly what i did but what you saying is different.

Comment: sry I edited the original snippet and image. Explaining a layout with words as a non-native speaker is hard...

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič Sorry i got busy. I understood what you meant with the updated the question. Glad thay you found a solution. I have updated my answer as well.